# How do I create a regex to ensure an array is correctly initialized in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for an array that will check that the array initialization is correct:

```
{1,2,3}
//correct

{1,2,3,,,}
//not correct
```

This is my current regex:

```
(?!\,\s*\})\{(.*?)\}*
```

How do I do this in Java?

Comment: Why doesn't the above work ?

Comment: What we're missing is the specific problem/error you're having with your current regex. What doesn't it match that it should? What does it match that it shouldn't?

Comment: Regex: `\{(\d+,)*\d+\}` should work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probem with your current regex is that it looks for a position before `{` that isn't followed by a `,`. There is only one such position in all the given strings, and that is between the beginning of the string and the `{`. Therefore, your regex will only match one character, i.e. `{`.

To fix the problem, you need to account for the format of the string inside the `{...}` part:

```
^\{\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*\}$
```

`\d+` matches the first value, and `(?:,\s*\d+)*` matches the rest.

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning-of-the-string anchor
\{          # match a literal { character
    \d+     # first element
    (?:     # beginning of the non-capturing group
       ,    # followed by a comma
      \s*   # and optional whitespace
      \d+   # and one or more elements
    )*      # make the whole group optional; allow for values like {1}
\}          # match a literal } character
$           # end-of-the-string anchor
```

If there could be values other than numbers, you could replace `\d` with the corresponding regex.

**Visualization:**

[image: Visualization]

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yU3lN4)

Comment: thank you very much! I understand now what I did wrong.

Comment: Nice thorough explanation. :)